# Rep League: A user's 2-year-long rep compressed in 1 week?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues, stackexchange.com

Consider this user, [Kozyarchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52490/kozyarchuk) from SO. The reputation league shows [he gains 1,592 rep out of 1,593 in the Aug 9th week (this week)](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stack-overflow/2010-08-09).

[image]

But the [rep graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52490?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) says otherwise.

[image]

(Also, the profile shows he got [21 badges on Aug 14th 19:00 – 19:26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52490?tab=activity#tab-top) right after he was seen on 18:58, which should have been given long ago. Is it another bug?)

Comment: That's how I know I've been using SO too much. I am on the front page =O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect he was merged with another duplicate account he had

yep:

> Moderator recalcs rep User.Merge() old rep = 31, new rep = 1593 14 hours ago

**Update**: Users who have their rep recalculated will automatically be recalculated on stackexchange.com that night.